# Custom Color picker not working on focus

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard

As you can see in the picture below, and I have a custom color picker under the tab of a view pager.  It works fine, but on the next tabs, there is a focusable view (an Edittext) where the keyboard appears. Whenever I swipe back to the color picker, this weird ring appears on the top left.

[image]

This is my [code](https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker/blob/master/src/com/chiralcode/colorpicker/ColorPicker.java) for the view:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line in your manifest file for the activity host the fragment:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```